# Only echo certain xml tags from xml output php

Tags: php, xml

I have this script with the array `$result` And I cant figure out why I'm not getting displayed the tags I want:
Let's assume I have this XML:

```
<result>
<domain>google.com</domain>
<update_date>27.6.17</update_date>
</result>
```

And my php script:

```
    foreach ($result as $values) {

    $domains = file_get_contents("https://www.somedomain.com/api?key=asdasf=$values");
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($domains);
    echo $xml->result->domain; 
    echo("<pre>".htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML())."</pre>");
 }
```

With this code Im getting displayed the full xml code...

```
    foreach ($result as $values) {

    $domains = file_get_contents("https://www.somedomain.com/api?key=asdasf=$values");
    echo $domains;
 }
```

Comment: if you simply want to show the xml data on your page then use `htmlentities` ~ ie: `echo htmlentities($domains);` but if you want to actually process the XML data you'll need to use DOMDocument ( or similar - SimpleXML etc )

Comment: Yea I want to display only certain tags, which was what I tried to achieve with simplexml but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: without seeing the xml it is hard to answer

Comment: Xml in the source code is looking like this .     '<name>peter</name><address>Peter St</address><number>123456</number>' And I either get displayed everything which is the case for the 2nd snippen or nothing which is the case for both other snippets

Comment: The XML you have posted is NOT valid - the closing tag to `update_date` does not match `update-date`

Comment: Sorry, wasnt intentional since this is only an example

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how to process an xml document using `DOMDocument` rather than `SimpleXML` ( which I don't use ) perhaps the following might give you some ideas.

```
<!--minbooks.xml-->

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>

/* 
    Rather than read the file first you can do $dom->load( $url )
    For the sake of the demo - consider $xml to be the return value 
    from your `file_get_contents` call
*/
$xml=file_get_contents( realpath( 'C:\wwwroot\xml\minbooks.xml' ) );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );

/* Find whatever nodes of interest */
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');

/* process the collection */
foreach( $books as $book ){

    $author = $book->childNodes->item(1);
    $title = $book->childNodes->item(3);

    echo $author->tagName . ' '.$author->nodeValue . ' '.$title->tagName .' '.$title->nodeValue . '<br />';
}


Output
------

author Gambardella, Matthew title XML Developer's Guide
author Ralls, Kim title Midnight Rain
author Galos, Mike title Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide
```

Using a representain of the xml you posted, corrected for incorrect closing tag, perhaps this might help.

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <results>
            <result>
                <domain>google.com</domain>
                <update_date>27.6.17</update_date>
            </result>
            <result>
                <domain>froogle.com</domain>
                <update_date>26.6.17</update_date>
            </result>
            <result>
                <domain>droogle.com</domain>
                <update_date>25.6.17</update_date>
            </result>
        </results>';


libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->recover=true;

$dom->loadXML( $xml );

$errs=libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();



$domains = $dom->getElementsByTagName('domain');
foreach( $domains as $domain ){
    echo $domain->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand. how the structure of this works. I mean If I dont have a huge nested xml sctructure why the for each loop ? In m xml there are no duplicate tags, and I dont want get the tag put out as well so can basically delete         `$author->tagName`

Comment: it was just to help you understand how to process the xml data. You have not shared the xml data you are using, only a little snippet which could be from any level with any parent. It is hard to know - add the actual xml to your question perhaps. Incidentally - I chose a simple piece of XML for the example rather than anything complicated

Comment: I dont think that the problem is within the xml file ? It's really basic. The most parents an element can get would be 3 I guess. I just dont understand why my code wont show the elements when I define the exact parents....

Comment: add the xml - redacted if necessary

Comment: what's that ? Never heard of it

Comment: redacted means to obscure/remove certain pieces of information if considered sensitive. ie: if you have secret information like passwords, credit card numbers  then hash them out wih xxx etc "    `edit (text) for publication.
    "a confidential memo which has been redacted from 25 pages to just one paragraph"
        censor or obscure (part of a text) for legal or security purposes.`"

Comment: But why should I use foreach if my real xml code only contains the domains tag 1 time